# How can I take each word in a string and append it in a list?

Tags: python, string, list

My String is:

```
wish = "Happy New Year"
```

Output:

```
word_list = ['Happy','New','Year']
```

Comment: And where are your attempts at this? SO isn't a coding service.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> wish = "Happy New Year"
>>> wordlist = wish.split()
>>> wordlist
['Happy', 'New', 'Year']
>>>
```

You can see the help of the string function split.

```
>>> help(''.split)
Help on built-in function split:

split(...)
    S.split([sep [,maxsplit]]) -> list of strings

    Return a list of the words in the string S, using sep as the
    delimiter string.  If maxsplit is given, at most maxsplit
    splits are done. If sep is not specified or is None, any
    whitespace string is a separator and empty strings are removed
    from the result.

>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

See the split method for the string.

```
"Happy New Year".split()
```

This will produce your array.

Comment: I feel like an idiot But Thanks a lot

Comment: Don't be so hard on your self. :) We were all been there. :)