# How do I replace a comma with a comma in double quotes using python

Tags: python

I have a list of industries formated as `Agriculture,Aquaculture,Forestry and Logging,Fishing Hunting and Trapping`and I need it to look like `"Agriculture","Aquaculture","Forestry and Logging","Fishing Hunting and Trapping"`

Thanks in advance

Comment: try like here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34554828/how-can-i-take-each-word-in-a-string-and-append-it-in-a-list/34554866#34554866

Comment: I tried that but it splits the result at both the comma's and spaces i.e. `['Agriculture,Aquaculture,Forestry', 'and', 'Logging,Fishing', 'Hunting', 'and', 'Trapping']` instead of `"Agriculture","Aquaculture","Forestry and Logging","Fishing Hunting and Trapping"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

```
text = "Agriculture,Aquaculture,Forestry and Logging,Fishing Hunting and Trapping"
newtext = text.replace(',', '","')
newtext = '"' + newtext + '"'
print(newtext)
```

**output**

```
"Agriculture","Aquaculture","Forestry and Logging","Fishing Hunting and Trapping"
```